# Can we recover from UncategorizedSQLException?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm basically working with dynamic data where I need to insert, update, or delete rows without having much control over the columns. The column names are selected dynamically based on the available data. For most cases, we have stored the read-only columns and avoid writing data to those specific columns. But there might still be a case where we might accidentally write data to a read-only column. For instance, here's an exception:

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE "Database"."Schema"."Table" SET "First Name" = ?, "Last Name" = ?, "Create Date" = ? WHERE id = ?]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [0]; Column [Create Date] could not be updated. This column is read-only.

Exceptions are caught easily, but what I want to know is, if there's a way to recover from these exceptions?

```java
    } catch (UncategorizedSQLException e) {
      String cause = e.getMessage();
      if (cause.contains("This column is read-only")) {
        // TODO: Recover Here
      } 
    }
```

I know that the problem is with the `Create Date` column, can I just remove that part of the query and run the statement again?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to change the created date. You're not creating the account, just updating. Personally I wouldn't change that value, and the original developer clearly doesn't want you to either. Are there any other columns in that table that have the effect of 'last updated'? If so, I'd update that field instead. If the company/application doesn't require you to keep track of changes, I'd just omit the create date on the update all together.

Comment: @JonR85 ‘Created Date’ is an example, there are fields like ‘message’, ‘city’, ‘state’, etc which are read-only columns. I don’t have control over the input data, hence need to validate the column in runtime.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't some sort of row version implemented? Worked on a database where no rows were allowed to be deleted or modified. Instead that would set 'flags' such as isDeleted to indicate to the app that it was removed. And if they needed to update the row they had a column 'rowVersion'. They would just create an identical row and increment rowVersion  by 1. Then the app would do a SELECT top 1..... Not saying that is your case, but if there are so many read only fields then it sounds as if the rows are not meant to be changed.

Comment: Further more, if you know those fields can't be changed, you could always just omit them all together instead of trying, failing and then recover. Because you already know it's going to fail.

Comment: The dataset is from cloud apps like Salesforce and HubSpot, they usually contain 100+ columns per table. As you are suggesting, most of the columns I know that are read-only are omitted. But still, I want to handle a case that I haven’t encountered yet.

Comment: Are these the tables you are looking at?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm